# Why and how is std::function<void()> allowed to be assigned to callables with return types in C++?

Tags: c++, std-function

The following code is legal C++:

```
int m() { return 42; }

int main() {
   std::function<void()> func, func2;
   
   func = m;
   func2 = [&]() -> std::string { return "This does not return void"; };
}
```

By passing `void()` to `std::function`'s template argument list, I assumed that meant `func` and `func2` must be assigned to functions/lambdas that return nothing. That is clearly not true.

Firstly, why is `std::function` designed to do this? This seems really surprising to me.

Secondly, how did they design `std::function` this way? I know `std::function` uses type erasure to be assignable to different types of callables, but since we explicitly supplied `void()`, shouldn't the different callables assigned to `func` and `func2`- whether they are lambdas or functions - only be returning `void`?

Comment: *You can't do this for example ...* - You [can](https://godbolt.org/z/v6dYhxsqx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves like

```
class function {
 public:
  void operator() {
    m();
  }
};
```

If you want to get errors, declare them like

```
std::function<void*()> func, func2;
```